# Is "as is the ___ so is her ___" valid in English?

Tags: spoken-english

I heard from someone:

> They are both jealous, **as is the mother so is her daughter.**

Another example relating to it reads as:

> **As is the question so is the answer.**

[Googling it](https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-oppo&sxsrf=ALeKk003rLXoBa_BupSWuHLCjlG5BrLIqQ%3A1599026168298&ei=-DNPX_bqEYjAoATljJfoBw&q=as%20is%20the%20question%20so%20the%20answer&oq=as%20is%20the%20&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAEYADIECCMQJzICCAAyBAgAEEMyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoECAAQRzoHCCMQ6gIQJzoCCC46BQgAEIsDOgUILhCLAzoLCC4QiwMQqAMQngNQr6MBWP3EAWCkzgFoAnABeACAAa8EiAGyHZIBBzMtOC4xLjGYAQCgAQGwAQ-4AQLAAQE&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp)  didn't provide anything helpful result.

Is it natural to the ears of a native speaker?

Comment: It is elegant and understandable, but native speakers are more likely to say (and this is a common phrase) "like father, like son" (or mother/daughter).

Comment: Which is pretty much exclusive to parental relationships (or, rarely, things being poetically likened to them). You wouldn't say "like question, like answer."

Comment: I told my French friend that my son could be a jerk sometimes, and he said "Comme père, comme fils".

Comment: @the-baby-is-you - compare "ask a stupid question, get a stupid answer", "garbage in, garbage out", "like shall cleave unto like", etc.